# How to remove (Click to sort Ascending) text from header of every column in this bootstrap-vue table?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I have a bootstrap-vue table that looks like this;

[image]

Here is the code;

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="pt-2 pb-3">Bootstrap Table</h1>    
    <b-table striped hover :items="items" :fields="fields" primary-key></b-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {      
      "fields": [
        {
          "key": "first_name",
          "label": "My First Name",
          "sortable": true,
        },
        {
          "key": "last_name",
          "label": "My Last Name",
          "sortable": true,
        },
        {
          "key": "age",
          "label": "Age",
          "sortable": true,
          "sortByFormatted": false,           
        },        
      ],
      "items": [
        { "age": -40, "first_name": "Dickerson", "last_name": "Macdonald"},
        { "age": 21, "first_name": "Larsen", "last_name": "Shaw" },
        { "age": 89, "first_name": "Geneva", "last_name": "Wilson" },
        { "age": 38, "first_name": "Jami", "last_name": "Carney" }
      ]
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

I want to remove the `(Click to sort Ascending)` text that appears in the header of every column.

I am puzzled why this text appears when it does not appear anywhere in the code.

I am using vue v2.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `label-sort-asc`, `label-sort-desc`, and `label-sort-clear` props to an empty string to remove the sorting labels:

```html
<b-table
 ⋮
 label-sort-asc=""
 label-sort-desc=""
 label-sort-clear=""
></b-table>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-remove-sorting-labels-from-bootstrap-vue-table?file=src%2FApp.vue)

Answer (score 1):

i hade same problem, it is not about load css files, it is about version conflict. when running `npm i bootstrap` it will install bootstrap **version 5**, while in bootstrap-vue site is expressed: **Bootstrap v4.3.1 is required, v4.6.1 is recommended**
so i ran `npm uninstall bootstrap` and then ran `npm install bootstrap@4.6.1` and it fixed

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported Bootstrap CSS files in your app entry point? Bootstrap uses the .sr-only class to hide that text and show it just on screen readers.

Look at the "Using module bundlers" section https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs

Comment: I did import the css files. 
`import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'`
Maybe my chrome browser behaves like a screen reader by default.

Comment: Same behavior in other browsers?

Comment: Yes. Tested on Firefox, Chrome, Opera browsers. All the same.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).