# Why does the v-bind shortcut : cannot be used for this property in this bootstrap-vue table?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I refer to this stackoverflow answer.

[How to remove (Click to sort Ascending) text from header of every column in this bootstrap-vue table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71312959/how-to-remove-click-to-sort-ascending-text-from-header-of-every-column-in-this/71316982#71316982)

The correct answer is below;

```
<b-table
 ⋮
 label-sort-asc=""
 label-sort-desc=""
 label-sort-clear=""
></b-table>
```

I add the v-bind shortcut `:` to the properties as below;

```
<b-table
 ⋮
 :label-sort-asc=""
 :label-sort-desc=""
 :label-sort-clear=""
></b-table>
```

With the `:` in front, there is no effect. For other properties, adding `:` is fine. I am confused why some properties need `:` and some others like `hover`, `striped` don't. How to know when I can use `:`?

I am using vue v2.6 and bootstrap-vue

Answer (score 2):

The colon is a shorthand syntax of v-bind directive and it's used for dynamically binding attributes/props to expressions.

So in short, in case the item you're trying to bind will not change and it is not a prop you're trying to pass downwards, it is useless.
If it is intended to be dynamic, you need some logic to control it or else it will do nothing.
[v-bind documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind)